# What Event can trigger GetFocus of a wx.Checklist Control?

Tags: focus, wxpython, listcontrol

I'm trying to use the focus of a checklist control to provide info to the user to help them in their selection. I can self.list.GetFocus on a check item event but can't seem to get the focus outside of a check item.
My goal is to have the user tab through the list and as the focus of the list changes it messages the status bar information from the focussed row so that the user is informed. The OnCheckItem selection is used to trigger another action. 
Can any one give me some direction?
Thanks

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    # encoding: ISO-8859-1
    """
    Simple Checkbox List Control.py

    """

    import wx
    import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix
    from wx.lib.pubsub import Publisher


    listhdr=('File', 'Info','Data')
    listdata=(  ( "file00","info00","data0"),
                ( "file01","info01","data1"),
                ( "file02","info02","data2"),
                ( "file03","info03","data3"),
                ( "file04","info04","data4"),
                ( "file05","info05","data5"))

    #=======================================================================
    #           CheckListControl Panel Class
    #=======================================================================

    class TestListCtrl(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.CheckListCtrlMixin, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
            # Initialize ListCtrl Widge
            listmix.CheckListCtrlMixin.__init__(self)
            listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
            self.setResizeColumn(3)

            self.checked = -1 # class container variable for the checked item index
            self.rowindex=[] # class container variable for selected row
            self.status={} # Dictionary to keep track of the checklist state
            #print self.GetFocus()
        def OnCheckItem(self, index, flag):
            self.msg1=''
            self.msg2=''
            if flag==True:
                #msg=str('Checked Item '+str(index))
                #The following insures only one checked item is checked at a time
                if self.checked==-1:
                    self.checked=index
                    self.msg1='Checked box %i '%(self.checked)
                else:
                    self.CheckItem( self.checked, False)
                    self.checked=index
                    self.msg1=' Checked box %i '%(self.checked)
            if flag==False:
                self.msg2=str('Unchecked Item '+str(index))
                #The following addresses checked item that was unchecked
                self.checked=-1
            self.status[index]=flag # set dictionary to current state of any changed item
            #print 'status ',self.status
            #msg='Check list Status: '+str(self.status)
            msg=self.msg2+self.msg1
            #print msg
            Publisher().sendMessage(('change_statusbar'), msg) # Communication with Main Frame
            print msg
            self.Refresh() # this just to insure the displayed list is current

    #=======================================================================
    #           CheckList Panel Class
    #=======================================================================            
    class CheckListPanel(wx.Panel):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, -1)
            self.SetBackgroundColour('blue')
            # Define CheckBoxList Layout
            self.list = TestListCtrl(self, style=wx.LC_REPORT) # Instantiate the checklist control
            self.list.InsertColumn(0, "File",width=100)
            self.list.InsertColumn(1, "Info")
            self.list.InsertColumn(2, "Data")
            self.list.Arrange()
            # Populate the List Table
            for entry in listdata:
                #self.list.Append([str(i), "", "It's the %d item" % (i)])   # this is from the source file template 
                self.list.Append(entry) # construct the table entries

            # add CheckListPanel widgets to vertical sizer
            self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
            self.sizer.Add(self.list,1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)  
            self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer) 

    #===========================================================================================================================
    #           Main Frame 
    #===========================================================================================================================
    class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
        def __init__(self, parent):
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, 'Panel with CheckBox List Control-Mixins Example', size=(700, 600))
            self.sb=self.CreateStatusBar()
            self.sb.SetStatusText("Check an Item")
            Publisher().subscribe(self.change_statusbar, 'change_statusbar')
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
            self.list = CheckListPanel(self.panel)

            # now add widgets to FramePanel
            self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) # create Sizer
            self.sizer.Add(self.list,1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, border=5)
            self.panel.SetSizer(self.sizer) # 

            self.Show()

        # Set the methods to receive PubSub transfers
        def change_statusbar(self, msg):
            self.msg=msg
            self.SetStatusText(msg.data)        

    app = wx.App(False)
    win = MainWindow(None)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I may have figured it out.The following code, when added to the CheckListPanel class will allow the selected item to be identified. I guess the list control must be instantiated before you can use the GetSelectedItem() method since it requires a wx.ID to bind the Event. I added this after populating the list setting the panel sizer

```
            # bind selected event to selected row
    wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED(self,self.list.GetId(), self.OnSelectItem)


def OnSelectItem(self, index):
    print 'Selected item index=',self.list.GetFocusedItem()
    msg='Selected item index='+str(self.list.GetFocusedItem())
    Publisher().sendMessage(('change_statusbar'), msg) # Communication with Main Frame
```